# table formatting in terms of length and breadth

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table}[]
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multirow{2}{*}{B} & \multirow{2}{*}{C} & \multirow{2}{*}{D} & \multirow{2}{*}{E} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{F}          \\ \cline{6-7} 
                   &                    &                    &                    &                    & G              & H              \\ \hline
\textbf{0.2}       & \textbf{0.5}       & \textbf{1}         & \textbf{0.2}       & \textbf{0.5}       & −1.8713360906  & −1.7640262021  \\ \hline
\textbf{0.3}       & 0.5                & 1                  & 0.2                & 0.5                & −1.9365758323  & −1.7648755545  \\ \hline
\textbf{0.4}       & 0.5                & 1                  & 0.2                & 0.5                & −1.9844365775  & −1.7572640364  \\ \hline
0.2                & \textbf{0.6}       & 1                  & 0.2                & 0.5                & −1.8893451634  & −1.7769110253  \\ \hline
0.2                & \textbf{0.7}       & 1                  & 0.2                & 0.5                & −1.9037201042  & −1.7845630194  \\ \hline
0.2                & \textbf{0.8}       & 1                  & 0.2                & 0.5                & −1.9084283289  & −1.78054097011 \\ \hline
0.2                & 0.5                & \textbf{1.1}       & 0.2                & 0.5                & −1.8638586434  & −1.75716821872 \\ \hline
0.2                & 0.5                & \textbf{1.2}       & 0.2                & 0.5                & −1.8563791180  & −1.75030388119 \\ \hline
0.2                & 0.5                & \textbf{1.3}       & 0.2                & 0.5                & −1.8488975550  & −1.74343325690 \\ \hline
0.2                & 0.5                & 1                  & \textbf{0.3}       & 0.5                & −1.7816929512  & −1.67995077275 \\ \hline
0.2                & 0.5                & 1                  & \textbf{0.4}       & 0.5                & −1.6940695909  & −1.59754625788 \\ \hline
0.2                & 0.5                & 1                  & \textbf{0.5}       & 0.5                & −1.60833298231 & −1.51669912930 \\ \hline
0.2                & 0.5                & 1                  & 0.2                & \textbf{0.6}       & −1.79104380621 & −1.69665633242 \\ \hline
0.2                & 0.5                & 1                  & 0.2                & \textbf{0.7}       & −1.72028938675 & −1.63324789889 \\ \hline
0.2                & 0.5                & 1                  & 0.2                & \textbf{0.8}       & −1.66248454886 & −1.58021088372 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Question: How can I control the height of each cell in this table?

Please help me

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned @js bibra in his comment, your question is actually duplicate to [column-and-row-padding-in-tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables). Let me add one more possibilities given in answers to question in the link, where behind vertical paddings are suggested some improvements to table design

- `S` column type defined in `siunitx` package,
- `etoolbox` package for defining robust command for marking cells with boldface numbers
- macro `\makegapedcells` for vertical padding, which is defined by `\setcellgapes{...}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}                          
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\sisetup{detect-weight,
         mode=text}
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
\caption{My table}
\label{tab:...}
    \label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{S[table-format=1.1]|}
                 *{2}{S[table-format=-1.11]|}
                 }
\hline
{\multirow{2.4}{*}{A}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{B}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{C}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{D}} & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{E}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{F}         \\ \cline{6-7}
        &       &       &       &       & {G}           & {H}           \\  \hline
\B  0.2 &\B 0.5 &\B 1   &\B 0.2 &\B 0.5 & -1.8713360906 & -1.7640262021 \\ \hline
\B  0.3 & 0.5   & 1     & 0.2   & 0.5   & -1.9365758323 & -1.7648755545 \\ \hline
\B  0.4 & 0.5   & 1     & 0.2   & 0.5   & -1.9844365775 & -1.7572640364 \\ \hline
0.2     &\B 0.6 & 1     & 0.2   & 0.5   & -1.8893451634 & -1.7769110253 \\ \hline
0.2     &\B 0.7 & 1     & 0.2   & 0.5   & -1.9037201042 & -1.7845630194 \\ \hline
0.2     &\B 0.8 & 1     & 0.2   & 0.5   & -1.9084283289 & -1.78054097011    \\ \hline
0.2     & 0.5   &\B 1.1 & 0.2   & 0.5   & -1.8638586434 & -1.75716821872    \\ \hline
0.2     & 0.5   &\B 1.2 & 0.2   & 0.5   & -1.8563791180 & -1.75030388119    \\ \hline
0.2     & 0.5   &\B 1.3 & 0.2   & 0.5   & -1.8488975550 & -1.74343325690    \\ \hline
0.2     & 0.5   & 1     &\B 0.3 & 0.5   & -1.7816929512 & -1.67995077275    \\ \hline
0.2     & 0.5   & 1     &\B 0.4 & 0.5   & -1.6940695909 & -1.59754625788    \\ \hline
0.2     & 0.5   & 1     &\B 0.5 & 0.5   & -1.60833298231& -1.51669912930    \\ \hline
0.2     & 0.5   & 1     & 0.2   &\B 0.6 & -1.79104380621& -1.69665633242    \\ \hline
0.2     & 0.5   & 1     & 0.2   &\B 0.7 & -1.72028938675& -1.63324789889    \\ \hline
0.2     & 0.5   & 1     & 0.2   &\B 0.8 & -1.66248454886& -1.58021088372    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great....Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
```

You can increase the height of each cell with the \arraystretch command. Pass the value to the argument, how much to increase the height.

Also, visit my youtube channel [WPG](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCy0vz71kvXSJSmrzHGL77Rg) for Latex tutorials.